# Washout filter for pitch and roll damper

Tags: flight-controls, yaw-damper

Washout filters are generally described in context of yaw channel where they  allow the turn command signal to not be dampened by the yaw damper in the feedback circuit as the low frequency signal is the pilot command.

By the same reasoning, are washout filters not necessary in pitch and roll channels also where damper may fight with the pilot  commands?

Answer (score 1):

Dampers are commonly implemented for pitch, roll and yaw damping. However of these three, only the yaw-damper has to allow a *non-zero static* component:

During a turn with constant bank angle, the pilot has to command a steady rudder input in order to achieve a [coordinated turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_flight). This results in a **constant non-zero** yaw-rate which a yaw damper without washout filter would continously counter-act. In pilots-terms, the yaw-damper would continously fight the pilots rudder command by counter-acting it.

For this reason a washout-filter (or high-pass filter) is introduced: This filter will only let through the high-pass component of the yaw-rate, therefore filtering out the steady-state yaw rate the pilot commanded. The yaw damper therefore does not "see" this steady state yaw-rate anymore and therefore does not fight it anymore.

For reference, I find it pretty nicely explained in [this open access lecture.](https://mitindia.edu/images/pdf/avionics_ppt/pitchrolland%20yawdamper.pdf)

Comment: Shared document (https://mitindia.edu/images/pdf/avionics_ppt/pitchrolland%20yawdamper.pdf) is very useful. As per page 12 of doc, washout is also required in pitch channel during pitch axis maneuvering.

Comment: Great! If you like my answer, please upvote it.